# How could the lifetime of a low earth orbit satellite be extended

Tags: orbital-motion, satellites

How could the lifetime of a low earth orbit satellite be extended?
I am studying for a test and wish to know a few methods.
Thanks.
Edit:

You are allowed to work with anything related to the satellite such as mass, shape, propulsion ect.

Comment: You mean orbital life, so it won't reenter yet? Otherwise it could be up to component degradation, which is a totally different story.

Comment: How about you post what you've tried, and what parameters you're allowed to work with? Otherwise we could suggest "remove the entire atmosphere to reduce friction drag."

Comment: Sorry, You are allowed to work with anything related to the satellite such as mass, shape, propulsion ect.
I have thought about increasing mass per cross sectional area to increase the lifetime.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - I considered adding a reference to "Space Balls: the Movie"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orbital life of satellite relates to the loss of angular momentum due to drag. So you could

- change aspect ratio: reduce the forward-looking area, reducing drag
- increase the mass (more angular momentum for same drag)
- regularly boost it (propulsion that counters the drag)
- put it in a higher orbit (less drag)

I considered whether making the orbit more elliptical would help - so it spends some of its time going more slowly, and at greater altitude. But I think that the net effect would be greater drag during the close-in part of the orbit, and probably the reverse effect. But you would have to do the math based on the density distribution with height at LEO altitudes.